# Guess my identity

Tags: word

If you think hard you can earn my name.

All that thinking might raise my power over you.

Dont worry, I can prevent that from showing.

I am alone... Yet there are many of me.

It burns you, not knowing my name.

Does it make you want to kill?

How far are you willing to take this game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> Degree

If you think hard you can earn my name.

> A college/university degree

All that thinking might raise my power over you.

> Powers (mathematical) use the term degree: 4 to the 12th degree is 4 to the power of 12

Dont worry, I can prevent that from showing.

> Degree is a brand name for antiperspirant/deodorant in the US

I am alone... Yet there are many of me.

> Relationships are measured in degrees (think Six Degrees of Kevin Bacon).

It burns you, not knowing my name.

> Heat is measured in degrees

Does it make you want to kill?

> First degree murder, e.g.

How far are you willing to take this game?

> Movement/motion is measured in degrees like "three degrees of freedom"

Comment: correct.  I did have a few different meanings for the explanation of each clue, but yours work as well.

Comment: What were the differences?

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer

> Discipline

If you think hard you can earn my name.

All that thinking might raise my power over you.

> You have to work hard to disciple yourself.

Dont worry, I can prevent that from showing.

I am alone... Yet there are many of me.

> You can be the master of your disciple in programming, writing and piano playing.

It burns you, not knowing my name.

Does it make you want to kill?

How far are you willing to take this game?

> You can be reckless without discipline.

Comment: Interesting thought, but no.  The answer applies to each line in a specific way.

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda dark but I guess this is

> Depression

If you think hard you can earn my name.
All that thinking might raise my power over you.

> Overthinking can lead to depression

Dont worry, I can prevent that from showing.

> Depressed person tends to hide their true feelings

I am alone... Yet there are many of me

> There are a lot of person who are depressed, but most of them most likely wants to be alone.

It burns you, not knowing my name.
Does it make you want to kill?
How far are you willing to take this game?

> Lastly, some depressed people commit suicide.

Comment: lol that is dark.  but not the answer Im looking for.

Comment: Yeah. I thought so, I just gave it a try. It's my first attempt here though.  Welcome to me. Haha